# Two resizable UIWebViews inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I need following view structure, with embedded 2 UIWebViews and 1 UIView (loaded from other xib).

But the problem is, because this need to be inside UIScrollView, with same impression like this is single page. (only vertical scrolling need to be enabled).

In those UIWebViews, html content is loaded from NSString.

Size (height) of UIWebViews and child view is variable.

[image: view XIB]

Any advice, how to do that?

Answer (score 7):

> Important: You should not embed
>   UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so,
>   unexpected behavior can result because
>   touch events for the two objects can
>   be mixed up and wrongly handled.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

However why cant you make a webview that has two iframes, with the content of your two html-files? Then attach this webview to the uiview?

Iframe resource:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: these two html contents are separated by the custom view (blue part, in the middle, of the screenshot).

Comment: Ok. Then I would read the quote in my post from Apple and reconsider the design.